# Spark Structured Streaming foreach Sink custom writer is not able to read data from Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have spark structured streaming job to read it from kafka topic. However on subscribe to topic, the job is not writing the data to console or dumping it to database using foreach writer.

I have class `DBWriter extends ForeachWriter<Row>` still the `open, process, close` method of this class are never invoked.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Have followed the instructions as per the [Spark Kafka integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html). Still its not working.

Spark Version 2.3.1
Kafka 0.10.0

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My Code is :

```java
spark.readStream().format("kafka").option.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "YOUR.HOST:PORT1,YOUR.HOST:PORT2")   
  .option("subscribe", "TOPIC1")    
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest") // read data from the end of the stream
  .load()
```

And

```java
Dataset<Row> selectDf = dataframe.select(dataframe.col("key")
  .cast("string"),org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json(dataframe.col("value")
  .cast("string"), schema).alias("data"));

selectDf.writeStream()
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000))
  .foreach(new DBWriterSink())
  .option("checkpointLocation","/tmp/chp_path/")
```

The input data has the following format :

DATA is in json format:

```
    {"input_source_data": 
    { "key1":"value1", 
    "key2": "value2"
     } 
    }
```

Comment: can you show us how the data looks like?

Comment: @mike I have updated question, with how data looks like, its in json format.

Comment: @mike, i was able to resolve the previous error, however my DBWriter Sink is not invoked and i am not able see any data received by the kafka . Have a test kafka producer which pushes data to kafka topci. any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was due to kafka configurations not set correctly. 
The topic subscription was not successful, the handshake was failing. After correcting the kafka properties correctly. 
Able to read the data, it was setting these properties additionally. After removing it, it started working. 
Able to read message and see the ForEachWriter being invoked too.

`properties.put("security.protocol", "SSL");`